# How can I loop through random numbers and stop at a certain number? Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to log numbers at random to the console, up to and inclusive of 6.

```
let i = 0

function test() {
    while (i < 6) {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)
        console.log(i)
    }
    if (i = 6){
        console.log(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

I have tried this but I get an error "Illegal break statement"

What is an illegal break statement and how can I achieve this?

Comment: you use break outside of your loop...

Comment: Comparison is done via `===`

Answer (score 0):

turn the if statement to an equality test contained in the while statement i.e.

```
while(i<6){...   
if(i==6)
     {...
     } 
}
```

Here is the full solution, note 6 is printed twice btw when the end condition is met.

```
let i = 0;

function test() {
    while (i < 6) {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        console.log(i);

        if (i == 6){
            console.log(i);
            break;
        }
    }

}
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the break statement. Because when  `i = 6` Then your loop condition false. Loop only run when `i < 6`.

```
let i = 0

function test() {
    while (i < 6) {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)
        console.log(i)
    }
     if (i == 6){
        console.log(i);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment) instead of the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

so your answer would be

```
let i = 0

function test() {
    while (i < 6) {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)
        console.log(i)
        if (i == 6){
            console.log(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use === too for type check

Answer (score 0):

- `i = 6` (assignment) should be `i === 6` to check for strict equality
- Instead of using `break`, you could simply use **recursion** which will recall the same function as long as *random* `r` does not equals `n`

```js
function test(max, n) {
   const r = ~~(Math.random() * (max + 1));
   console.log(r);
   if (r !== n) test(max, n);
}

test(6, 6); // max 6, stop if 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need no check for equalness, because `6` is the only random value where the loop stops.

And because of it, you need not to `break` the loop nor to `return` the function.

The loop constuction is to have at least one loop. In this case, you better use a `do ...while` loop, because the first check is always `true`.

```js
function test() {
    let i = 0;

    do {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        console.log(i);
    } while (i < 6)

    console.log('final value', i);
}

test();
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using the break statement inside function, not inside loop that is why you're getting the issue. Move your condition and break statement inside while loop.

Fix:

```
   let i = 0
    
    function test() {
        while (i < 6) {
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)
            console.log(i)
            if (i == 6){
               console.log(i);
               break;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Throw error to stop execution

```
if (i === 3) {
            throw new Error(); // break
        }
```